# Injecting model in controller not working

Tags: magento2, model

I have created a custom module and I want to inject my model in a constructor , but when I inject the model class then my controller stops working.

```
namespace DD\Reservations\Controller\Url;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use DD\Reservations\Model\QuoteReservation;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class TestResponse extends Action{

    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
       // QuoteReservation $quoteReservation,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo 'This is from test response';
        $this->logger->debug('This is debug from test response');
    }
}
```

If i uncomment the commented line from constructor my controller won't display the echo message anymore , neither the log message.

This is my model file:

```
<?php

namespace DD\Reservations\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class QuoteReservation extends AbstractModel{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\DD\Reservations\Model\ResourceModel\QuoteReservation::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you must **flush and clear your cache after injecting any class in your constructor**. You can upgrade your setup if flush cache does not work as expected.
So run below command:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

and give write permission to var and pub if they have not.

You can use below code and let me know if still face any problem.

```
namespace DD\Reservations\Controller\Url;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use DD\Reservations\Model\QuoteReservation;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class TestResponse extends Action{

    private $logger;
    protected $quoteReservation;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        QuoteReservation $quoteReservation,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->quoteReservation = $quoteReservation;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo 'This is from test response';
        $this->logger->debug('This is debug from test response');
        $quoteReservation = $this->quoteReservation->create();
        //use as you wish
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked not the create method cause it's not a factory but it compiled and everything. I was running only cache:flush i thought it was enough. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `$quoteReservation` as a variable. just after `$logger`

```
protected $quoteReservation;
```

and then

```
public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        QuoteReservation $quoteReservation,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->quoteReservation= $quoteReservation
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

Comment: No that is not the problem. Didn't work. I thought that i can't use models inside controllers but core controllers from magento 2 use them.

Comment: Can you please add your Model file?

Comment: <?php

namespace DD\Reservations\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class QuoteReservation extends AbstractModel{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\DD\Reservations\Model\ResourceModel\QuoteReservation::class);
    }
}

Comment: `$this->_init('DD\Reservations\Model\ResourceModel\QuoteReser‌​vation'); ` please change this line and try again